# Is derefrencing ptr while logging error wrong design?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, logging

while going over some old code that I didnt wrote I noticed something like this(simplified)

```
//switch case on a msg received from a queue,...
//... get_function returns msgtype and ptr
switch(msgtype)
//...
default:
{
    MYLOGGER<< "Unknown message" << (*ptr)->some_member_var <<"\r\n";
}
```

So I thought on trying to change it to

```
        default:
{
    MYLOGGER<< "Unknown message...\r\n";
    MYLOGGER<< "..." << (*ptr)->some_member_var << "\r\n";
}
```

because in case ptr is junk I fear crash before logging even begins?
Am I rigth in this example? Also in general should one avoid doing dereferencing when logging errors.

EDIT: regarding MYLOGGER, it is a macro that ends up with this:
logger class with overloaded operator <<  that does ostream flush() in dtror, so no need for endl.

Comment: There is no difference in terms of safety between the two versions of code, other than you may get your 'Unknown message..' pumped out before a potential crash happens. You should check if the `ptr` is valid before dereferencing

Comment: It's usually good practice to not touch code that's not broken. In your case, the operator << may do magic (or insane) things that a simple line rearrangement might break. All otherwise, seems sane. As long intentions are sane, dismiss this comment. The value might be captured by reference as well. Then it's screwed. And if you use endl? Omg, you're flushing with a reference to potentially invalid memory! What? operator -> ?!? X_X

Answer (score 2):

If the current code would crash, then so would your new code as well. A better solution would be to simply check for nullptr before dereferencing, and printing a special message if that's the case.

```
if(ptr == nullptr)
    MYLOGGER<<"invalid null message\r\n";;
else
    MYLOGGER<< "Unknown message " << (*ptr)->some_member_var <<"\r\n";
```

Given that (as per your comments) the operator<< already performs a flush, this is as safe as we can get, and even in the event of a crash (perhaps if ptr is invalid, but not nullptr), we will most likely see the "unknown message" in our logs.

Comment: Having no idea how `MYLOGGER` is implemented (it might not be an `ostream`), your answer is quite preposterous. But actually, it's even worse, the crash could occur *before* the first call to `MYLOGGER` if the compiler removes null checks based on the fact that if it's not checked here it was not necessary to check it before either! See the link from my answer to delve into the wonderful word of compilers optimizations and how they use *undefined behavior* as assertions.

Comment: yes, but the point is that you would know why it crashed... ofc you could go with debugger through crash dump, but at least you know what caused the crash from logs...

Comment: @MatthieuM. First, take a deep breath and calm down. Then, read furhter: I assumed that it was an ostream or equivalent, and if this is not the case I assumed the original poster would comment on that. Also, the point of my solution was not to avoid a crash or solve all the world's problems in the most general case scenario, but simply to improve chances that at least something might show up in the log in case of a crash.

Comment: @Agentlien: Regarding `ostream` I see no such assumption in your answer; regarding the crash, this is the kind of beliefs that lead programmers astray during debugging sessions. I am not saying that this may not work (here), I am saying that it is better to explain what undefined behavior really entails.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl I've updated my answer as per your comments. This is a safer, nicer solution if you think the ptr may be nullptr.

Answer (score 2):

I'll defer to [What every C programmer should know about undefined behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html) by Chris Lattner (who better than a compiler writer to speak about compiler surprises ?).

The TL;DR version is: when it's undefined, there is not *temporal* safety because of the compiler optimizations. Therefore, the two versions you presented are strictly equivalent.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Does not change anything. Undefined behavior trumps temporal guarantees, so the crash could occur prior to the first call to `MYLOGGER`.

Comment: default: is not undefined, just not expected...(aka it is a logic flaw, not like race condition that causes  UB)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: dereferencing a null pointer **is** undefined behavior (thus the crash you generally get).

Comment: yes, but the flush is called before dereferencing...(because MYLOGGER creates temporary logger instance).  yeah theoretically UB could cause program to delete log file and replace it with animated gif of invisible pink unicorn, but it is unlikely.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: did you read the link at all ? Suppose you have something like: `if (ptr) { ptr->foo(); } MYLOGGER << "x"; MYLOGGER << ptr->bar();`. The compiler will look at `if (ptr)` and say: it's non-null, because later on we do `ptr->bar()` without any check; and will rewrite it as `ptr->foo(); MYLOGGER << "x"; MYLOGGER << ptr->bar()`. And lo and behold, the crash occurs before anything is logged!

Comment: I know that example, it is famous... Linux kernel had a bug due to that retarded compiler optimization that is radioactive pure evil.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know what the message is, you should not be trying to interpret its contents in any way.  You can log the value of `ptr` itself, but you don't really know where it points to, so don't deference it.

Answer (score 0):

Your logger may work asynchronously, or make the log persistent asynchronously in which case the second code wouldn't be more useful than the first.
Anyway, accessing an unchecked pointer is undefined behavior and in this case, possibly crashing because an unknown message was received seems a bit harsh.